# Using asp:login control inside an updatepanel control in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, updatepanel

I have an update panel control wrapping a login control.  I want the user after logging in to go to a changepassword control, which is already setup.  But when I enter the correct username and password fields, and click Login, the page refreshes. How do I stop this?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateLogin" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Login id="LoginAuth" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>

            The username and password controls are here.

             <asp:imagebutton id="Login" Enabled="true" OnClick="Login_OnClick" CommandName="Login" runat="server" AlternateText="Login" ImageUrl="powerstats/inc/img/login_up_gray.png"></asp:imagebutton>

            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:Login>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe [LoggedIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin.aspx) event. It is called once the user is authenticated successfully.

```
<asp:Login id="LoginAuth" runat="server" OnLoggedIn="LoginAuth_LoggedIn">
    ....
</asp:Login>

protected void LoginAuth_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Changepassword.aspx");
}
```

Comment: I wanted it to appear in a layer on the same page, is that possibe?

Comment: You can set `LoginAuth.Visible = false` and `PasswordRecovery.Visible = true` inside **LoggedIn** event.